# How do I deprecate a custom Maven Archetype?

Tags: maven, deprecated, maven-archetype

Is it possible to deprecate custom maven archetypes installed on nexus ?

I was thinking may be use something like this -

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
        http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.myorg.myarch</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-archetype-custom</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Archetype - maven-archetype-custom</name>
**<deprecated>TRUE</deprecated>**
</project>
```

Re-install the archetype so that when a user tries to create a project using this, they get a message saying its deprecated.

Comment: Are you working with an SNAPSHOT version of the archetype ?

Comment: Well, yes. My requirements is I need to rename the existing archetype and then install them on Nexus.So, I was thinking if I can deprecate an existing archetype and install my re-named archetype or rename and archetype so that the existing ones are also re-named.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to [relocate your artifact](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-relocation.html) but a real kind of deprecated configuration etc. does not exist. In your case i would recommend to remove the SNAPSHOT versions from the Nexus and really deploy a release version like 1.0.0. The Idea of artifacts in general in Maven is they are as they are...which means a rename will never happen, cause you can't know if someone has already used it.